# Gradle Copy task always UP-TO-DATE

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

I've seen this question posted numerous times, but I've not yet found an answer that matches my specific use case.

I'm created a bunch of config files from a template, after iterating over a config file containing environment properties.

The problem is that if I amend src/properties/ENV.gradle with some new values, it's ignored when I call the task on the basis that it's already "UP-TO-DATE".  I'm not using doFirst or doLast, which is one of the common reasons this happens.

My workaround so far is to include

```
outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
```

which forces the config files to be recreated every single time regardless of what Gradle calculates, but it feels like an awful hack.   Is there a better way?

Here's the code:

```
task createConfigs

def addTemplateTasks(aProject, env, config) {
    aProject.with {
        task "templateCopy_${env}"(type: Copy) {
            from "src/templates"
            include "server.config.template"
            into "${buildDir}"
            rename { file -> "server.config.${env}" }
            expand(regionConfig)

        }
        createConfigs.dependsOn "templateCopy_${env}"
    }
}

def envFile = new File("${project.projectDir}/src/properties/ENV.gradle")
def envConfig = new ConfigSlurper().parse(envFile.text)
envConfig.each { env, config ->
    addTemplateTasks(project, env, config)
}
```

**SOLUTION:**
My case was a bit specific in that I was expecting the Copy task to notice "config" changing, without telling it explicitly care about it (see accepted answer below).  Here's the change that fixed the problem:

```
def addTemplateTasks(aProject, env, config) {
    aProject.with {
        task "templateCopy_${env}"(type: Copy) {
            inputs.property("environmentConfig", config)
```

The first arg (in quotes) is the name for this property, the second is the actual value.

Now, when I change a property in the ENV.gradle file and run "gradle -i", I see this:

```
Task ':component-foo:templateCopy_DEV' is not up-to-date because:
  Value of input property 'environmentConfig' has changed for task ':component-foo:templateCopy_DEV'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only *input* of your copy task, is the `src/templates` directory. Unless the content of `src/templates` doesn't change an the copied *output*s are still present, your task will be considered *UP-TO-DATE*.

The problem is that your copy task actually has a second input which Gradle doesn't know about: Your `config`/`regionConfig` object.

Try to add the `config` object (or a hash of the objects values) to the inputs of the copy task using `inputs.property` or `inputs.properties`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining so clearly.  I'll update my OP with the solution.  :-)